# Connecting MySQL with R

Tags: mysql, r, database, rmysql

This is how I am trying to connect MySQL to R.

```
db <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user='username', password='pwd',dbname=dbx, host = 'local', port = 3306)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> Error in .local(drv, ...) : Failed to connect to database: Error:
>   Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module
>   could not be found.

What to do?

Comment: Are you using DBI package to connect with MySQL?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. I have tried with the DBI package and cannot get the problem fixed. I am also following detailed instructions to get connected between R and MySQL with no success on this specific point.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a **function** to retrieve the query.

```
library(RMySQL)
sqlQuery <- function (query) {

        # creating DB connection object with RMysql package
        DB <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="user", password="password",
                        dbname="databaseName", host="host")

        # close db connection after function call exits
        on.exit(dbDisconnect(DB))

        # send Query to obtain result set
        rs <- dbSendQuery(DB, query)

        # get elements from result sets and convert to dataframe
        result <- fetch(rs, -1)

        # return the dataframe
        return(result)
}
```

And then just:

```
new_dataframe <- sqlQuery("SELECT * from table")
```

Hope that helps

Comment: there is nothing about this that will solve OPs `Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded` issue.